# ImportError: No module named pip._internal

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, installation, kivy

So I am working on installing Cython for Kivy so I can package my project into an iOS file that I can test on my iPhone. Here is the link I'm following: https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-ios.html

The issue I run into when installing something like Cython (or anything else for that matter, I have tried matplotlib for instance, and get the same result), it returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
ImportError: No module named pip._internal
```

I have gotten this error in the past, and am still trying to figure it out. I used this post a few days ago:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025189/pip-is-not-working-importerror-no-module-named-pip-internal/1026848?newreg=64574707bd3540948f5c54ec80d2b371

which helped me to install kivy.

However, I am now having these issues with downloading other libraries. When I try to `sudo easy_install pip`, one would expect it would tell me that I already have pip installed. However, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install-2.7", line 7, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

Clearly something is going on here. I am trying to solve once and for all, is there something wrong with my pip? Did I install it wrong? Is it missing this 'pip._internal' file or something? Lastly, of course, I want to be able to successfully download libraries without the pkg_resources error

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I'm using a Mac with Python 3.6 in PyCharm CE

Comment: @hoefling should I download the files? I forgot to mention, I'm on Mac using python 3.6 and PyCharm. I'll update the post so everyone knows this

Comment: Well, since your downloading via the command prompt I am assuming that your using the System Interpreter and not the Pyharm Virtualenv Environment?

Comment: @Rob I am using Terminal. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Addison PyCharm CE is not a terminal. If your trying to access modules downloaded from the terminal in PyCharm CE then chances are you will need to set your interpreter (in PyCharm) to: System Interpreter. Otherwise, you will need to attempt to download your modules through PyCharm instead of the terminal.

Comment: @Addison In PyCharm, File:Default Settings  Are all the modules you are attempting to use in your code located here? Are any of them located in here? If not, then that is why you can't use them in PyCharm.

Comment: @Rob oh I see, when I go to project interpreter I see I already have Cython. I didn't realize that there was a difference between installing through terminal vs installing through the terminal window in PyCharm. When I go to PyCharm, I can import whatever I want (like matplotlib, something I didn't previously have installed), and there are no issues

Comment: @Addison Great!